I wanted to make an auto job for file monitoring status
In this file monitoring this will check if the files are recieved or not in the shared paths and if recieved then what's the extension of the file recieved if .pro then the file is processed and if .error then the file is errored out and its size and everything will be then monitored.

What do you have to check on the files, some kind of script?  Once you have that, we can discuss putting the information in a database.

I want to make a job for file monitoring status which will run daily and check for the files if it exists or not and if exists then what's the extension of the file of .pro then the file is processed and if .error then file is errored out and then I need 5 columns where first column will be of the sharedpath second of file date and time third of total files recieved fourth column of the file name and fifth of the file size and all this should come as an output

You need to write application code to crawl the file system, then do INSERTs into a database table.  Plus another app to SELECT from that table to display the results -- possibly sorted in various ways and maybe LIMITed to the latest or biggest or whatever.

You need to write application code:

Crawl the file system, then do INSERTs into a database table.  This would probably be invoked periodically via cron or the equivalent.
Another app to SELECT from that table to display the results -- possibly sorted in various ways and maybe LIMITed to the latest or biggest or whatever.  This would probably be a web page.
Some way to purge old data.
etc.

In this design, the database is merely a "persistent storage" for the information found.
MySQL does not have any tools to do your specific tasks, only to assist in store and retrieve the data.
